# How to build a Foreign Key in mySQL

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys

I have 2 tables - 1st table:

```
CREATE TABLE COFFEE_SHOP 
(
    shop_id INT,
    shop_name VARCHAR(50),
    city VARCHAR(500),
    state CHAR(2),
    PRIMARY KEY (shop_id)
);

INSERT INTO COFFEE_SHOP (shop_id, shop_name, city, state)
VALUES (1, "store g", "melbourne", "CA"),
       (6, "store x", "palms", "FL"),
       (4, "store b", "grandi", "TX"),
       (2, "store a", "flonce", "GA");
```

2nd table:

```
CREATE TABLE EMPLOYEE 
(
    employee_id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    first_name VARCHAR(30),
    last_name VARCHAR(30),
    hire_date DATE,
    job_title VARCHAR(50),
    shop_id INT references COFFEE_SHOP(shop_id)
);

INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE (first_name, last_name, hire_date, job_title)
VALUES("jim", "jordan", "2002-03-05", "barista"),
      ("george", "washington", "2015-03-02", "manager"),
      ("abraham", "lincon", "2020-04-07", "grinder"),
      ("barack", "obama", "1999-05-09", "front office"),
      ("george", "bush", "2150-03-10", "tender");
```

Question: why does the following query return null and how do I fix it such that the 2nd table actually references the first and uses the shop_id as a foreign key in the second table.

Query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM EMPLOYEE
```

This query returns null for all `shop_id` values. How do I connect the two tables so that each employee has a referenced `shop_id` from `coffee_shop`?

Also I tried making the foreign key in `EMPLOYEE` with the following code and it did not work that way either.

```
FOREIGN KEY(shop_id) REFERENCES COFFEE_SHOP(shop_id)
```

Comment: *How do I connect the two tables...?* By supplying a value for the column `shop_id` in the INSERT statement.

Comment: MySQL is not magic. It won't know which shop an individual works at unless you tell it. You don't provide that data. Why do you think MySQL can fill it in for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For example, if you wish to tell MySQL that Jim Jordan is working in the Melbourne's shop Store G, you need to do the insertion this way :

```
INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE (first_name, last_name, hire_date, job_title, shop_id) VALUES("jim", "jordan", "2002-03-05", "barista", 1)
```

The foreign key needs to know which primary key fits your needs in the other table.

As a foreign key can't be NULL, you must provide the related *shop_id*.